# Html 5 Form validation without Form

Tags: html, validation

Can a html5 form validation

```
<form>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here..." required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

can it be done without a Form

```
<div>
    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email here..." required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use the constraint validation API. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api. For instance, you can call `element . checkValidity()`. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/checkValidity. For example:

```
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var valid = email . checkValidity();
if (!valid) ...
```

or use the `invalid` event which is fired when `checkValidity()` fails:

```
email.addEventListener("invalid", function() { alert("Email invalid"); });
```

You can use `setCustomValidity` to set the validity status and/or error message:

```
if (!email.value) email.setCustomValidity("Email is missing");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the errors in the page, instead of just receiving a boolean with the validation result, you can use:

```
document.gelElementById('email').reportValidity();
```