# How to trigger the html5 validation without using <form> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have normal form which looks like this(You can ignore the inside fields as they are all input fields):

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="float: none;">
   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 2px solid #efefef;">
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <h4>Type</h4>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6" style="border: 2px solid #efefef;">
         <div class="card-body">
            <div class="form-group row ">
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <label>Appeal Reason</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <label>Appeal Amount</label>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">Penalty</div>
               <div class="col-md-2"></div>
               <div class="col-md-4">
                  <input type="text"
                     class="form-control"
                     id="applReason" 
                     name="applReason" required> <span
                     id="fromDateError" style="color: red; font-weight: bold"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <input type="number"
                     class="form-control"
                     id="applAmount" name="applAmount"
                     required>
                  <span id="toDateError" style="color: red; font-weight: bold"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-3">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="applPenalty"
                     name="applPenalty" required> <span
                     id="consignmentNoError"
                     style="color: red; font-weight: bold"></span>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-2">
                  <button type="submit">+</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <h5>Remarks</h5>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="100">

     </textarea>
   </div>
   <button type="submit"  id="sub" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Due to some reasons,I have not wrapped all these fields inside `<form></form>` tag but when I perform the submit operation by clicking the 
 `<button type="submit"  id="sub" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Submit</button>`,it is not performing html5 validation. This on click function is trigerred and it is getting posted.How to validate html5 features without using `<form>` tag?

```
$( "#sub" ).click(function() {
          alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
       //ajax code to submit
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html 5 Form validation without Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758303/html-5-form-validation-without-form)

Comment: input/button type`submit` works for `form` only.  Mean it submits the parent form. if you do not have any form, `submit` will not work. as you are saying for some reason in html you don't want to wrap in `form` then using javascript wrap it. but to trigger the form submit you must have `form`, yes if you want to check the `validation` on each field individual then of course you can refer the above link by @Cue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the constraint validation API for that. Refer [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-constraint-validation-api).
Example-

```
var emailId = document.getElementById("id");
var valid = emailId . checkValidity();
if (valid) {
//perform operation
}
```

Comment: How to popup error message window just as same as submit the form if invalid?

Comment: I would also like to know how to trigger the validation popup message.

Answer (score 0):

Use `element.reportValidity()` to both *validate AND show* the popup if it fails.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/reportValidity

Answer (score -1):

Form validations will be triggered by buttons **inside** a form automatically. 
But for manual triggering you can use `checkValidity`.
Here's a sample bin for that case:

https://jsbin.com/misotahupu/edit?html,js,console,output

You probably shouldn't be doing HTML5 validation without the `<form>` element. [Here's more literature on forms](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html)